# DAG for contiguous subsequence of maximum sum

Tags: dynamic-programming, dag

I have trouble understanding DAG behind the "contiguous subsequence of maximum sum problem". Let's say I denote by `S(i)` maximum of sums of contiguous subsequences ending in i. So S(i) are my subproblems. To calculate `S(i)` I need `S(i-1)` so the edge will be between node `i` and `i-1`. Denoting the sequence by `a_i`, I think my DAG will look like this:

`a_1 -> a_2 -> ... -> a_n`

I feel like this doesn't tell me anything. In Chapter $6$ of the book Algorithms ([Dasgupta et al.](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf#page=4)), they find a correspondence between problem and edges in the graph. I don't really see that here. I don't know if I grasped the idea of DAG right, something feels off.

Comment: I could not see this problem in Chapter 6 of [Dasgupta](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf#page=4). Can you check it again.

Comment: The problem is given in [Exercise 6.1](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf#page=181) of Dasgupta et al. But it does not say anything about DAG.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't but I want to find it. The DAG I wrote about is mentioned in 6.2 with the problem of Longest increasing subsequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You grasped the idea right. For the problem of finding "contiguous subsequence of maximum sum", the DAG is indeed $a_1 \to a_2 \to ... \to a_n$, since the sequence is contiguous.

To get a better feel for DAG, you should consider the problem of finding an "**increasing** subsequence of maximum sum" problem. By increasing subsequence, I mean that $a_{i} \leq a_{j}$ for any two consecutive elements $a_{i}$ and $a_{j}$ in the sequence.
Note that, an increasing subsequence might not be contiguous. And, to calculate $S(i)$, you will need $S(j)$ such that $a_{j}\leq a_{i}$. So there will be an edge between the nodes $j$ and $i$ if and only if $a_{j}\leq a_{i}$ and $j < i$. You will get your DAG. Here, DAG might not contain the edges between $a_{i}$ and $a_{i+1}$, as it was in the previous problem.

You can also consider the problem of finding the "subsequence of maximum sum". Here the subsequence is neither contiguous nor increasing. Here DAG will contain an edge between every pair of nodes $a_{i}$ and $a_{j}$ for $i<j$. And, the maximum value is trivially the sum of all positive values in the array.